# Create Cookie From ID?

Tags: javascript, cookies, location, geo

I found this great script that finds a users zip code based on their longitude and latitude. Through reading the code I found out that there must be a status id to make the information become visible. The question I have is, is it possible to make a cookie of the information put into the status id. So it would put a zip code based on the person and I would like to make a cookie of that zip code to use it further on my website. It uses geolocation and inserts the information into google and gets a zip code. So I would like to capture that zip code and create a cookie out of it if possible. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

 <body>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
<center>
<p id="status"></p>
<script>
$(function(){
var GETZIP = {
  getLocation: function(){
     $('#status').text('Searching...');
     if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GETZIP.getZipCode, GETZIP.error,     {timeout: 7000});//cache it for 10 minutes
     }else{
        GETZIP.error('Geo location not supported');
     }
  },
  index: 0,
  error: function(msg) {
     if(msg.code){
        //this is a geolocation error
        switch(msg.code){
        case 1:
           $("#status").text('Permission Denied').fadeOut().fadeIn();
           break;
        case 2:
           $("#status").text('Position Unavailable').fadeOut().fadeIn();
           break;
        case 3:
           GETZIP.index++;
           $("#status").text('Timeout... Trying again (' + GETZIP.index +  ')').fadeOut().fadeIn();
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GETZIP.getZipCode, GETZIP.error,  {timeout: 7000});
           break;
        default:
           //nothing
        }
     }else{
        //this is a text error
        $('#error').text(msg).addClass('failed');
     }

  },

  getZipCode: function(position){
     var position = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
     $.getJSON('proxy.php',{
        path : "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position+"&sensor=false",
        type: "application/json"
     }, function(json){
        //Find the zip code of the first result
        if(!(json.status == "OK")){
           GETZIP.error('Zip Code not Found');
           return;
        }
        var found = false;
        $(json.results[0].address_components).each(function(i, el){
           if($.inArray("postal_code", el.types) > -1){
              $("#status").text(Your zip code: + el.short_name);
              found = true;
              return;
           }
        });
        if(!found){
           GETZIP.error('Zip Code not Found');
        }
     });
  }
}
GETZIP.getLocation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is your question just "how do I store a zipcode in a cookie?".  Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: No. Its how to capture the zip code and store it in a cookie. The zip code seems to be defined as "el.short_name" and I can't find a way to store it properly as a cookie.

Comment: Why can't you just put `el.short_name` into a cookie?  What did you try?  What problem did you have?

Comment: I have tried anything with the "el.shortname". I have tried to get the id status into a form value so that I could easily just create a cookie out of the form value. But I had no luck with that.

Comment: Just create a cookie with `el.short_name` right after this line `$("#status").text(Your zip code: + el.short_name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code properly retrieves the zip code in `el.short_name`, you can just store the value, right after it's retrieved:

Here's a function for creating a cookie:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "", date;
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Here's a modified version of getZipCode that writes the cookie right after retrieving the zip code:

```
  getZipCode: function(position){
     var position = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
     $.getJSON('proxy.php',{
        path : "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position+"&sensor=false",
        type: "application/json"
     }, function(json){
        //Find the zip code of the first result
        if(!(json.status == "OK")){
           GETZIP.error('Zip Code not Found');
           return;
        }
        var found = false;
        $(json.results[0].address_components).each(function(i, el){
           if($.inArray("postal_code", el.types) > -1){
              $("#status").text(Your zip code: + el.short_name);
              createCookie("zipcode", el.short_name, 365);
              found = true;
              return;
           }
        });
        if(!found){
           GETZIP.error('Zip Code not Found');
        }
     });
  }
```